# Pointers overriding older pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been given this task and having quite a bit of trouble with information being replaced by new data. When a new customer is created they have to create a new basic account. This works fine but as I'm trying to allow customers with multiple types of accounts each with their own rules such as student/current which each contain their own values.

For some reason my Money value of a account becomes whatever value is currently set and for some reason each account even for different customers share the value inside. So if account1 has £200 then account2 is then created with £300. account1 will then be set to £300.

Customer.h

```
Customer(std::string sFirstName, std::string sLastName, 
    std::string sAddressLnA,
    std::string sAddressLnB,
    std::string sCity,
    std::string sCounty,
    std::string sPostcode,
    AccountManager* bankAccount);

    AccountManager* getAccount(void);

    //outside class
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, Customer& customer);
```

Customer.cpp

```
//Part of a method but i've shrunk it down
AccountManager account(H);
AccountManager accRef = account; //This the issue?
Customer c(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, &accRef);
customerList.insert(c);
showPersonDetails();

//Output
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Customer& customer)
{
    output << customer.getFirstName() << " " << customer.getLastName() << endl
        << customer.getaddressLnA() << endl
        << customer.getaddressLnB() << endl
        << customer.getcity() << endl
        << customer.getcounty() << endl
        << customer.getpostcode() << endl
        << (*customer.getAccount()) << endl;
    return output;
```

AccountManager.h

```
class AccountManager
{
private:
    double money;
public:
    AccountManager(double amount);
    ~AccountManager(void);
    double getMoney();

};

//Print
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, AccountManager& accountManager);
```

AccountManager.cpp

```
using namespace std;

AccountManager::AccountManager(double amount)
{
    money = amount;
}

AccountManager::~AccountManager()
{
}

double AccountManager::getMoney()
{
    return money;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, AccountManager& accountManager)
{
    //Type of account
    output << "Account Money: " << accountManager.getMoney() << endl;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Note that `AccountManager accRef = account;` does NOT create a reference, you're copying the `account` object.

Comment: Also, try to provide a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. The provided code has nothing to do with the stated issue. You'll get an answer quite fast if you provide some code that simply  compiles and runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AccountManager accRef = account; //This the issue?
Customer c(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, &accRef);
```

You create an account as a local variable, pass *a pointer to it* to the `Customer` constructor, the `Customer` stores that pointer, then "a method" terminates, the local variable passes out of scope, and the `Customer` is left with a dangling pointer. Then you dereference the pointer and get strange results.

(Why does `Customer` store the account by reference anyway?)